# memory leak issue

Tags: iphone

I am loading images to `UITableViewCell` using the following function. But when I run my app with Debugger its getting crashed at `[pool release]` whenever I scroll my `UITableView`. What might I do to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
- (void) loadImage{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    imageURL = [imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];      
    //NSLog(@"img url cell**** %@",imageURL);  
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
    //self.image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an autorelease pool in this method? In general, you shouldn't be creating and releasing your own pools arbitrarily.

Comment: I added NSAutoReleasePool because because am getting this in my GDB  
_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x364d6b0 of class UIImage autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: I'd suggst to look how the pool was handled in your main.m file and doing it the same way. There is a [pool drain] missing somewhere.

Comment: @Philipp In a reference-counted environment you can use release instead of drain.

Comment: This needs more context. Who calls loadImage? To which class does it belong? How does the property of image look like?

Comment: ya. I have used like my main.m only..in which situation have to give like [pool drain]..?

Answer (score 5):

By the fact that you are using a NSAutoreleasePool I guess that load image is running in a thread that is not the main thread. Is this Correct? If that is the case you are making a UIKit invocation (self.image = ...) in this non-main thread and this is a possible source of the crash you are experiencing. All UIKit updates must be made in the main thread, since UIKit is not thread safe. Try replacing:

```
self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
```

by

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Notice I'm guessing the name of the setter is **setImage**:, you may need to correct if the setter selector has a different name that.

Comment: yes .I am calling loadImage as a seperate thread ([NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];).So i have to write seperate code for @selector(setImage:)..?

Comment: You can either create a  method to set the image or use the one created by @synthesize. @synthesize creates a getter and a setter method for each property (unless you tell it not to). Beware of name collisions, @synthesize will create setImage: thus if you create your own method for setting the property either don't name it setImage:, or define the "setter" in in the @property definition.

Comment: To keep it simple try defining -(void)mySetImage:(UIImage *)im{self.image = im} and use this selector (@selector(mySetImage:)) for the performSelectorOnMainThread: call.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.but am using this([cell.thumbImageView setImageURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURL,  [array2 objectAtIndex:1]]]) to set the image in my cellForRowAtIndexpath.is this correct..?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific of the cell you are using. However, the principle says the same. Update the image in the main thread as detailed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is recommended to use [pool drain] instead of [pool release].
But I see another potential issue here: according to your code, you defined initially imageURL outside of your newly created autorelease pool (I don't see any alloc/init for imageURL, where is coming from? is it a table cell instance?) then you reassign imageURL with a newly allocated and autoreleased string: [imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:...]. Finally when you release the pool the new imageURL is release, so at the end what you had is a leak of the previously allocated imageURL. I can expect at this point that when exiting from the inner autorelease pool the run loop autorelease tries to release imageURL again (for example, but I need to see your code to fully understand) which has been deallocated.

Can you try to assign the result of stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: to a different name (e.g. myImageURL)?

Comment: Just a comment who marked this answer as "not useful": try to run this code and then tell me if it works: 

NSString *mystr;

-(void)test {
 NSLog(@"Mystr=%@",mystr);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
 
 mystr = [NSString stringWithString:@"AA"];
 NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 mystr = [mystr stringByAppendingString:@"BB"];
 [p release];
 
 [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

then try again by deleting the [p release] or assigning BB to mystr2

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things wrong here.

Firstly, your need of an autorelease pool quite clearly suggests that you're not doing this work on the main thread. UIKit is not thread-safe. Any UI work needs to be done on the main thread or undefined behaviour will occur, such as crashes.

Secondly, you're using what looks like a synchronous URL download of an image. Correct me if you're loading it from a file URL on disk. A synchronous image download is probably the reason why you've moved this into a separate thread, because it was blocking your UI right? One of the first things you should learn about network access it to never use a synchronous API on the main thread. Have you considered looking at the `NSURLConnection` class in order to do an asynchronous download?

Thirdly, this needs to be re-architected so that the image download isn't directly linked to the display of the cell.

Displaying the table cell should be done on the main thread with the rest of the UI. When the cell is displayed, it should make a call to download the image asynchronously. The image download should be cached, and the cell should be informed via a delegate callback when the image download is complete. It should then display the image.

You can wrap these kind of things up in `NSOperation`s and use `NSOperationQueue` to manage them. Please, look at the documentation for these classes and checkout the example code for them to learn how to use them.